# How to change the font size of metrolabel of MetroFramework?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have downloaded and reference the MetroFramework for my Winforms application.

The download link is [enter link description here](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui).

In my program, I tried to set the font size of the characters in the metrolabel but failed. Following is my code:

```
        this.lblDay.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblDay.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 156);
        this.lblDay.Name = "lblDay";
        this.lblDay.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 19);
        this.lblDay.TabIndex = 0;
        this.lblDay.Text = "00";
        this.lblDay.Font = new Font(new FontFamily(System.Drawing.Text.GenericFontFamilies.Serif),10);
```

I tried to set `this.lblDay.Fontsize =20` but it gives me error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That is not possible.  You'll have to use the FontSize property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MetroFramework you can't se the font size directly. You have to basically edit the code in MetroFramework project and create a new size like "Extreme" or something and then define what that size is. I have done this in the past and its not very difficult. Just add the MetroFramework projects to your solution and trace how a MetroLabel gets initialized. That will be a good starting point.

Comment: I managed to change it. It isn't difficult as you have mentioned and you advice has given me a good guide.